# Drawing 2D polygons in openGL

Tags: c#, opengl-es, webgl, sprite

I'm using DuoCode to try and draw 2D polygons in webGL. I wrote specific shaders for this purpose that take 2D-vertices and z position as well as some other data:

```
<!-- Fragment shader program -->
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
    uniform highp vec3 uColor;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    uniform int uSamplerCount;

    void main(void) {
    highp vec4 texColor =vec4(uColor, 1.0);
    if(uSamplerCount > 0)
        texColor = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<!-- Vertex shader program -->
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute highp vec2 aVertexPosition;
    attribute highp vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform highp vec2 uPosition;
    uniform highp float uZLayer;

    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(uPosition + aVertexPosition, uZLayer, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    }
</script>
```

In this case I disabled textures and just try to draw a white polygon. The shaders compile without error.

I create my vertex buffers like this:

```
    public void UpdateBuffers()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Updating buffers");
        System.Console.Write("Vertices: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < rotatedPoints.length; i++)
            System.Console.Write(rotatedPoints[i] + ", ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(" ");
        System.Console.Write("texCoords: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < texCoords.length; i++)
            System.Console.Write(texCoords[i] + ", ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(" ");
        System.Console.Write("Triangles: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++)
            System.Console.Write(triangles[i] + ", ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(" ");

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, bVertexPositions);
        gl.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, rotatedPoints.As<ArrayBufferView>(), GL.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, bTextureCoords);
        gl.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoords.As<ArrayBufferView>(), GL.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bIndices);
        gl.bufferData(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles.As<ArrayBufferView>(), GL.STATIC_DRAW);
    }
```

which again goes without errors and gives me the following output:

> Updating buffers
>   Vertices: 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10,
>   texCoords: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>   Triangles: 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2,

(Vertices are 2-component)

I'm trying to draw a single polygon like this:

```
gl.viewport(0, 0, (int)canvas.width, (int)canvas.height);
gl.clear(GL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
testSprite.Draw(aVertexPosition, aTextureCoord, uColor, uPosition, uZLayer, uSampler, uSamplerCount);
```

a denotes attributes, u denotes uniforms locations here.

The drawing itself looks like this:

```
public void Draw(uint aVertexPosition, uint aTextureCoord,
        WebGLUniformLocation uColor, WebGLUniformLocation uPosition, WebGLUniformLocation uZLayer, WebGLUniformLocation uSampler, WebGLUniformLocation uSamplerCount)
    {

        //position
        gl.uniform2f(uPosition, this.position.x, this.position.y);
        gl.uniform1f(uZLayer, this.position.z);
        gl.uniform3f(uColor, 1f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        gl.uniform1i(uSamplerCount, 0);

        //vertex data
        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, bVertexPositions);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, bTextureCoords);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(aTextureCoord, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bIndices);

        //texture
       // gl.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
       // gl.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
       // gl.uniform1i(uSampler, 0);

        //draw
        gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, triangles.length, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }
```

Again no errors in the JS console.
Unfortunately the screen just stays black. I think there error might be connected to the fact that the vertice array has 2 components, but I can't figure it out. I thought I had understood the basics of openGL but apparently I was wrong, since this should really not be that hard of a problem. Yet I can't get anything drawn. If you need it I can post the remaining code, like the buffer creation but I think my mistake must be somewhere in this code. I hope this is not too much of a "find the bug somewhere in my code" post, but I really don't know where to go from here, I just can't figure out my mistake.

EDIT: Found my mistake, I was passing int to the element index list, but I marked them as ushort

Comment: I'd like to see your entire code for this. Could you create a plunker or similar for this? On first blush, my instinct is that your vertices are out range (-1 to 1,  unless some scaling is being done with a homogenous coordinate somewhere), or that nothing is in fact compiling your script.

Comment: Sprite code: http://pastebin.com/LZVLGS59 Programe code: http://pastebin.com/ZvYPMJNU

Comment: Remaining code: http://pastebin.com/rLbVdGYD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was here:

```
 gl.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, triangles.length, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

triangles was actually of type int, not ushort